# CodePipeline fails on CodeDeploy stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Getting this error: "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems"

I was following this yt tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voWo0hF8mQQ
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmIEm.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your instance has codedeploy agent successfully installed and is in running state.
you can follow this link to install code deploy agent on your instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html